# MVC3 Check a checkbox on page load

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on an MVC3 app that has several forms.  When I get to one form if a variable (ViewData) is true I want to check a checkbox by default but I have no idea how to do this.  Any help?

Thanks,

Rhonda

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using `Html.CheckboxFor()`. Here's a simple example. If you have a model with a property `IsSet` then you can do this:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsSet)
```

Good luck.

Comment: If you're old skool (i.e. MVC 2), you can do <%= Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsSet) %>.

Answer (score 2):

With the [HtmlHelper extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.checkbox.aspx) :

```
<% Html.CheckBox("name", bool.Parse(ViewData["isChecked"])) %>
```